# Free comment reply system like intensedebate?

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql-server

Is there any free script in PHP/MYSQL or in ASP.NET/SQL Server for comment reply system like intensedebate.com. In intensedebate we can reply to any comment or reply. I need the similar free script which I can modify according to my website needs.

Please let me know if anybody knows any system like this or if anyone has some concept which can guide me to create a system (db tables and script) like intensedebate.com have.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about any free complete script, but take a look at this PHP Class. Almost upto what you may need.

http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/01/27/php-class-for-threaded-comments/